# JSP send data to Java class

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm looking to send information after each link click to my java class to help increment a counter and to change an object which is held in my bean (myGame) which holds an array of 'cases'. I understand that I can increment a counter using JS, but i'd like to keep all game logic within the bean if possible.
I have considered using forms and changing the anchor to a submit button, however, I'd like to keep that the player can no longer click the link after it the case is eliminated.
The printCase(int) function works by finding the corresponding case in the array, checking the value of a boolean (is the case is eliminated from the game [deal or no deal]) and then prints the amount of money held in the case if eliminated; the case number if it is not.

I have about a dozen cases.

```
<jsp:useBean id="myGame" scope="session" class="dealOrNoDeal.GameLogic"/>
<table border="1" id="dndTable">
    <form action="/../doStuff.jsp" method="post">
        <tr>
            <td> <%= myGame.printCase(0) %> </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

I've also considered changing my bean to a servlet. Does that work? Can you have a bean in a servlet?
Thanks all.

Update: I've made printCase now print the tag that it's within now, as well. Prints as a submit button if the case is not opened, prints as a `<p>` if it is (I need it to use the class). Attempted putting the `<td>`s in there as well, but it somehow messes up the formatting.
I'm now looking to get the name of the one button that was clicked, any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is you problem/question?

Comment: What is a way I can send data to my Java class with my current format? If that's not possible and I change my anchor tags to 'submit' buttons, can I do something similar that renders the button useless after it is clicked once (and is then showing the case amount) ?
Preferably, if I can somehow use java 'on click' rather than javascript, that would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about understand completely your qestion. But i'll try:

U have 2 ways:

- You have to build a jquery where on each button click u call a servlet where u send information to your java class;
- Using DWR: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html